# Rails initializer file not loading in production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, websocket, rubygems, websocket-rails

I have patched websocket-rails gem to work in my development setup.

I created a file websocket_patch.rb under config/initializers and copied the code from **websocket-rails-0.7.0\lib\rails\app\controllers\websocket_rails\delegation_controller.rb**

```
module WebsocketRails
  class DelegationController < ApplicationController
  end
end
```

The namespace **Namespace1** has been added to reference the file and match up with my project structure.

```
Current project structure is like 

Project folder
      |_namespace1-/app/../application_controller.rb
      |_namespace2-/app/../application_controller.rb
```

So i have to override the default access in delegation_controller.rb.

```
  Project folder
     |_config/initializers/websocket_patch.rb

  module WebsocketRails
    class DelegationController < Namespace1::ApplicationController
    end
  end
```

It works properly in development enviroment but breaks in production. It goes back to gem file for the reference instead of loading the file under config/initalizers

```
websocket-rails-0.7.0/lib/rails/app/controllers/websocket_rails/delegation_controller.rb:11:in `<module:WebsocketRails>': uninitialized constant WebsocketRails::ApplicationController (NameError)
```

Rails version: 3.2.22.4, Ruby version: 2.2, there is no specific configuration in production for loading the initailizers.
Let me know if you need more info around this

Comment: Is the gem isn't just specified in the development group within the gem file is it?

Comment: No it's not under any of the groups. common to all

Comment: Can you share a sizeable error trace?